# Setting foreground color for TreeViewItem from code behind

Tags: wpf, treeview

I need to set custom color for TreeViewControl in runtime so I need to add style in code.
This is my tree control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Client.WPF.CommonControls.Controls.Common.Tree"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Client.WPF.CommonControls.Controls"
         xmlns:sf="http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ClientCore.ViewModels;assembly=ClientCore"
         xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Client.WPF.CommonControls.Models"
         xmlns:metaInfos="clr-namespace:Base.MetaInfos;assembly=PresentationBase"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <models:TreeViewModel></models:TreeViewModel>
</UserControl.DataContext>


<TreeView Name="TreeViewNodes" ItemsSource="{Binding TopNodes}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding SelectedStarElement}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type metaInfos:Element}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption}"
                       Foreground="Blue"
                       TextAlignment="Left"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And when i'm building window with control i fire this method to add styles;

```
public void AdjustAppearance(Appearance appearance)
    {
        if (appearance!= null)
        {
            if (!appearance.BackColor.isEmpty)
            {
                Background = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.BackColor);
                TreeViewNodes.Background = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.BackColor);
            }
            else
            {
                Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                TreeViewNodes.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }

            if (!appearance.ForeColor.isEmpty)
            {
                Foreground = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.ForeColor);
                TreeViewNodes.Foreground = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.ForeColor);
            }

            if (!appearance.BorderColor.isEmpty)
            {
                BorderBrush = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.BorderColor);
            }

            if (appearance.BorderThickness >= 0)
            {
                BorderThickness = new Thickness(appearance.BorderThickness);
            }

            if (appearance.ForeColor != null && !appearance.ForeColor.isEmpty)
            {
                //Foreground = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.ForeColor);
                //TreeViewNodes.Foreground = StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.ForeColor);
                //StyleHelper.SetStyleForControlItemContainerStyle(
                //    this, typeof(TextBlock), TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, appearance.ForeColor);

                Style textStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
                textStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, StyleHelper.GetSolidColor(appearance.ForeColor)));
                TreeViewNodes.Resources.Add("textStyle", textStyle);

                //Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
                //StyleHelper.SetStyleForControlItemContainerStyle(
                //    this, typeof(TreeViewItemAdv), TreeViewItemAdv.ForegroundProperty, appearance.ForeColor);

            }
            if (appearance.FontData.SizeInPoints > 0)
            {
                FontSize = StyleHelper.PointsToPixels(appearance.FontData.SizeInPoints);
                TreeViewNodes.FontSize = StyleHelper.PointsToPixels(appearance.FontData.SizeInPoints);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appearance.FontData.Name))
            {
                FontFamily = new FontFamily(appearance.FontData.Name);
                TreeViewNodes.FontFamily = new FontFamily(appearance.FontData.Name);
            }

            this.FontWeight = appearance.FontData.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
            TreeViewNodes.FontWeight = appearance.FontData.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
            this.FontStyle = appearance.FontData.Italic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal;
            TreeViewNodes.FontStyle = appearance.FontData.Italic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal;
        }
    }
```

I have tried with different methods, one like this:

```
    public static void SetStyleForControlItemContainerStyle(Control control, Type typeOfControl, DependencyProperty property, object value)
    {
        if (typeOfControl == null) return;
        var itemContainerStyle = (control as ItemsControl)?.ItemContainerStyle;
        if (itemContainerStyle == null) itemContainerStyle = new Style(typeOfControl);
        itemContainerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(property, value));
    }
```

Could somebody provide me with any guidance? I feel lost right now because all other properties work. I can set text to be bold for example.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you set the color of the `TextBlock` statically to `Blue`. It won't change by setting `TreeViewItem.Foreground`.
Also don't create styles or templates in C#.

Don't explicitly set the `TextBlock.Foreground`. Just set the `TreeViewItem.Foreground`. By default `Control.Foreground` will be inherited by child elements. This means the `TextBlock.Foreground` will implicitly inherit the `TreeViewItem.Foreground`.

Create a resource that serves as the binding source for the default `Style` of the e.g., `TreeViewItem` and add it to the application's `ResourceDictionary` in the *App.xaml*. It should contain all dynamic properties of your layout e.g. colors, margins, font, font size etc.

**ThemeProvider.cs**

```
class ThemeProvider : DependencyObject
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty TreeViewItemForegroundProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TreeViewItemForeground",
    typeof(Brush),
    typeof(ThemeProvider),
    new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Blue));

  public Brush TreeViewItemForeground
  {
    get => (Brush) GetValue(ThemeProvider.TreeViewItemForegroundProperty);
    set => SetValue(ThemeProvider.TreeViewItemForegroundProperty, value);
  }
}
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionar>
      <ThemeProvider x:Key="ThemeProvider" />
    </ResourceDictionar>
  </Application.Resources>
<Application>
```

**Tree.xaml**

```
<TreeView Name="TreeViewNodes">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type metaInfos:Element}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption}"
                 TextAlignment="Left"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" 
              Value="Binding Source={StaticResource ThemeProvider}, Path=TreeViewItemForeground}" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void AdjustAppearance(Appearance appearance)
{
  var themeProvider = Application.Current.Resources["ThemeProvider"] as ThemeProvider;
  themeProvider.TreeViewItemForeground = appearance.ForeColor;
}
```

Comment: Hello @BionicCode, thank you very much for very detailed answer. The ThemeProvider aproach worked like a charm. I am really gratueful. I have used in only in user control, not whole app.xaml.

And in my original post i added Foreground="Blue" just to test and forgot to delete the line but this is not relevant now.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am happy I could help. I just used your example color _Blue_ to show how to define a default value. You can use it locally to dynamically customize a control or use it global to e.g. theme the application.

Comment: Yes, that's just what i did - used color defined in object. Thanks again!